# Как отследить изменение файлов в галерее android

Tags: android, файловая-система, android-intent

Подскажите пожалуйста, как программно отследить изменение файлов в галерее android. Хочу сделать по таймеру сканирование файлов и сверять их с БД, но возможно в android 4.4+ есть некий механизм, который срабатывает при изменении файловой системы в галерее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен `ContentObserver` его надо повесить на `Uri` на котором "висит" MediaScanner (`MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`)

```
class MediaScannerObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public MediaScannerObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    //при изменении Content'а будет вызываться эта функция
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        //blah-blah
    }
}

//регистрируем наблюдателя/слушателя - приблизительно так
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, false,
    new MediaScannerObserver(new Handler()));
```